# How do I set uTorrent to download files in priority of their naming order?

Tags: utorrent

I'm trying to watch a TV series that is being downloaded kinda slow, but the speed is enough to get the next episode and start downloading the one following it. uTorrent allows some control over which file I want to be downloaded next. First, I can set its priority to either High, Normal and Low, and second, I can totally disable a file's downloading, so if that file is being shared too vigorously and it obstructs downloading of the other files, even if I set their priority to High. So, basically, 4 priority grades. But those I have to reset manually, when the most awaited file is downloaded.

How do I automate this process? Or is there a way to set priority in more ranks than just the default 3?

note: I'm not interested in downloading *a single file in sequential order*, as the "related" question section might suggest, I'm trying to *prioritize the file order* automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the prioritize by file order option? It always seems to download better than manually sorting.

Comment: strangely, it does work better for some reason